# Django choice not rendering properly using {% if %}

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I'm trying to render sort of like a short name for each of the preferred languages in my models.py file, depending on the one the user inputs on the form.py, but it is currently only rendering "EN" across each individual object. How can I fix this?

thanks all in advance...

Models.py

```
preferred_language_choices = [
    ('English', 'English'),
    ('Español', 'Español'),
    ('Français', 'Français'),
    ('Other', 'Other')
]
preferred_language = models.CharField(choices=preferred_language_choices, max_length=50, blank=False, null=True)
```

forms.py

```
class GroupForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        exclude = ('admin_approval', 'slug',)
```

page.html

```
{% if group_model.preferred_language == English %}
    <div class="container">
      <p>EN</p>
    </div>
    {% elif group_model.preferred_language == Español %}
    <div class="container">
      <p>ES</p>
    </div>
    {% elif group_model.preferred_language == Français %}
    <div class="container">
      <p>FR</p>
    </div>
 {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a *string* instead of a variable, so:

```
{% if group_model.preferred_language == 'English' %}
    <div class="container">
      <p>EN</p>
    </div>
    {% elif group_model.preferred_language == 'Español' %}
    <div class="container">
      <p>ES</p>
    </div>
    {% elif group_model.preferred_language == 'Français' %}
    <div class="container">
      <p>FR</p>
    </div>
 {% endif %}
```

I would however *strongly* advise *not* to do this in the template. In fact, probably the best place is the model itself, with:

```
preferred_language_choices = [
    ('EN', 'English'),
    ('ES', 'Español'),
    ('FR', 'Français'),
    ('__', 'Other')
]
preferred_language = models.CharField(
    choices=preferred_language_choices,
    max_length=2,
    blank=False,
    null=True
)
```

Then you can render in the template the key with:

```
<p>{{ group_model.preferred_language }}</p>
```

and you can render the "full" name of the language with:

```
<p>{{ group_model.get_preferred_language_display }}</p>
```